# How can I disable text-selection in webkit browsers when using jQuery UI .draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, webkit, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I can't seem to disable text-selection in webkit browsers when using jQuery UI .draggable(). I've tried using the webkit specific css (-webkit-user-select and -webkit-user-drag) in various combinations but haven't had any luck.

Here's a jsfiddle where you can reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dmosher/8ZGLR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disableSelection is your friend here.

> .disableSelection() is an undocumented
>   (for now)  core utility. It's useful
>   for making text elements, or elements
>   that contain  text, not
>   text-selectable. For example, if you
>   have a draggable element, you  may not
>   want text selection to occur when the
>   user goes to drag the element.

You may want to create a helper so it looks obvious that something is being dragged.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZGLR/1/)

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I've got a helper in the production implementation, this was just an isolation to attempt to remove any other conflicting problems. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not satisfied with this answer, as it prevents the user from selecting and copying text within the draggable row. :(

Comment: Yeah there is that too, but it begs the question _should_ a user be allowed to both copy text out of and drag the same element?

Comment: @Justin Searls - you cant have it both ways!