# Overrides the native behavior when selecting texts on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I would like to know if there is a way to overrides the native behavior when you select texts on mobile browser. I am trying to support both iPhone and Android devices by providing my own action bar.

Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

Although you could quite simply use the `selectionchange` event to show your 'actionbar' alongside the native functionality, if you would want to 'replace' the native behavior you would need to either fake the entire selections from scratch or use the `selectionchange` event and the second the the selection is made you wrap the selected text with a coloured span element for example and cancel the real selection (whilst showing your actionbar), the trouble with this method would be that 1) the native actionbar might show for a split second and 2) the experience will be different from what the user is used to possibly having dangerous effects. If on the other hand you would want to do the selections from scratch you should use the `user-select` css property to disable text selection and next figure out based on the touchstart and thouchend which text to 'select' (with coloured spans) (realistically only possible in an extremely controlled environment (for example a text-only reader application)).

Please note that this will not work in Firefox and Opera as the `selectionchange` event is not fired there and you would need to use a `touchend` event handler on the document + stopping bubbling of all other touchend events to support opera mobile and firefox mobile. (Credit for the fact that `select` doesn't work and `selectionchange` should be used goes to Tim Down)

Comment: +1. However, the `select` event isn't supported in WebKit on regular content (as opposed to form inputs). You'd need to use `selectionchange` instead, which was added to WebKit a couple of years ago. http://jsfiddle.net/EPbXQ/

Comment: Oh, I see, the `select` event is apparantly only fired for input elements. Changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @DavidMulder, I thought you had the solution. But none of those events are being fired on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.1. But the event is fired on my Samsung Fascinate running Android 2.2. About the Galaxy Nexus, even if the event could fire. The getSelection() is always empty.

Comment: Just so you know, I am working on it right now. And one more thing, you probably shouldn't develop on alpha builds and custom roms, because that's *never* representative.

Comment: Android 4.0+ browsers are seriously messed up, going to retry sometime soon if I can muster the motivation (got extremely frustrated at certain findings).

Comment: I have found a "solution". I just simulate text selection in Javascript. Using DOM Manipulation and traversing techniques.

Answer (score 2):

**Reference:**

[**jsFiddle Demo with Plugin**](http://jsfiddle.net/ebEqu/1/)

The above jsFiddle Demo I made uses a Plugin to allow you to ***prevent any block of text from being selected*** in **Android** or **iOS** devices (along with desktop browsers too).

This does **not** interfere with other markup you may have, such as jQuery `.click();` event listeners as demonstrated in the jsFiddle.

It's easy to use and here is the sample markup once the jQuery plugin is installed.

**Sample HTML:**

```
<p class="notSelectable">This text is not selectable</p>

<p> This text is selectable</p>
```

**Sample jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.notSelectable').disableSelection();

});
```

**Complete jQuery Plugin:**

```
$.fn.extend({
    disableSelection: function() {
        this.each(function() {
            this.onselectstart = function() {
                return false;
            };
            this.unselectable = "on";
            $(this).css('-moz-user-select', 'none');
            $(this).css('-webkit-user-select', 'none');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, this other [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4597241/11958910) may be useful too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to prevent selection, you could use some CSS like

```
body 
{ 
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```